# Can I exclude a specific property from auto configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and trying to use "PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" to load external properties files from filesystem,
but I got an error like below:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties@3ec11999 failed:

    Property: server.environment
    Value: BETA
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.core.env.Environment] for property 'environment'; ...
```

This is because spring-boot tries to auto-config "ServerProperties" and "ServerProperties" looks like:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class ServerProperties
        implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer, EnvironmentAware, Ordered {

    ...
    private Environment environment;
    ...
}
```

So it tries to "parse" any property with a "server" prefix.

Unfortunately our legacy properties file happens to contain an irrelevant property called

```
server.environment=BETA
```

So spring-boot tries to convert string "BETA" to an "Environment" object.

Is there a way that I can exclude "server.environment" from spring-boot's autoconfigure ?

Comment: Could exclude private Environment environment; or rename this filed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can exclude single property, but you can make trick Spring Boot to preserve original `Environment` object while converting `String` to `Environment`.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class OriginalEnvironmentPreservingStringToEnvironmentConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private static final Set<ConvertiblePair> CONVERTIBLE_TYPES;

    static {
        Set<ConvertiblePair> types = new HashSet<>();
        types.add(new ConvertiblePair(String.class, Environment.class));
        CONVERTIBLE_TYPES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(types);
    }

    private final Environment environment;

    public OriginalEnvironmentPreservingStringToEnvironmentConverter(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return CONVERTIBLE_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(final Object o, final TypeDescriptor typeDescriptor, final TypeDescriptor typeDescriptor1) {
        return environment;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if there wouldn't be any side effects though. In simple scenario it does work fine.